# Failed to get json data

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I want to get json data from API, but it seems not working. I think code will talk by itself

```js
var URL = 'https://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/?method=getQuote&format=json&lang=en';

getData(URL);

function getData(source){
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        
    xhr.onload = function(){
        if(xhr.status === 200){
            data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            console.log(data);
          
            
        }
    }

    xhr.open('GET', source, true);
    xhr.send(null);
}
```

This code gives console Error `Failed to load https://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/?method=getQuote&format=json&lang=en: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.`

I have suspicious that it might be CORS, but I have no idea how to fix it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use: https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/ service, by prepending your URL:

*`https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/`https://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/?method=getQuote&format=json&lang=en*

*You must consider that it is a free service that may not be 100% available.*

> This API enables cross-origin requests to anywhere.

Something like this:

```js
var URL = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/?method=getQuote&format=json&lang=en';

getData(URL);

function getData(source) {
  xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onload = function() {
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
      data = xhr.responseText;
      console.log(data);
    }
  }
  xhr.open('GET', source, true);
  xhr.send(null);
}
```